# Is there a way to list available/configured AWS CLI profiles?

Tags: command-line, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to list available/configured AWS CLI profiles, other than parsing `~/.aws/config` and/or `~/.aws/credentials` for profile names?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can list profiles in your aws config/credential files using [`list-profiles`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/configure/list-profiles.html):

```
aws configure list-profiles
```

This is working for me with aws-cli version 2.0.8.

Comment: It's new in AWS CLI 2.x.

Comment: this should be bumped as as the answer in 2020

Comment: Bumped (in 2022 :)

Answer (score 15):

(Answering my own question.)

No, there is not.

I wrote two scripts that include the parsing I ended up using. For anyone interested, they're available in two GitHub repositories:

[awscli-mfa](https://github.com/vwal/awscli-mfa) and [aws-scripts](https://github.com/605data/aws-scripts)

There are two related blog articles : "[AWS CLI Key Rotation Script for IAM Users revisited](https://random.ac/cess/2017/10/28/aws-cli-key-rotation-script-v2/)", and "[Easy MFA and Profile Switching in AWS CLI](https://random.ac/cess/2017/10/29/easy-mfa-and-profile-switching-in-aws-cli/)".

(update 2019-01-27: the blog article *"Easy MFA and Profile Switching in AWS CLI"* is out of date as it refers to the `awscli-mfa.sh` script version 1.x while the rewritten 2.x has been released. An updated blog article is forthcoming, but in the meanwhile, please refer to the [awscli-mfa](https://github.com/vwal/awscli-mfa) repository documentation)

Comment: As an answer lower down states, AWS CLI v2 has `aws configure list-profiles`. Unfortunately, v2 is bit more tedious to install & update than v1 (as of 2020, at least)

Answer (score 15):

Parsing `~/.aws/credentials` was simple enough for me.

`$ cat ~/.aws/credentials | grep -o '\[[^]]*\]'`

**=> [default] [other_profile] [other_profile2]**

I also aliased the command into `aws-profiles` by adding the following line into my `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias aws-profiles="cat ~/.aws/credentials | grep -o '\[[^]]*\]'"
```

**utilizing a profile**

add `--profile <profile_name>` to your aws command. Ex. `$ aws s3 cp  ~/my.pdf s3://my_bucket/my.pdf --profile other_profile2`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse the `config` file rather than `credentials` (which I found was more practical when using a [source_profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-role.html) rather than having unique credentials defined in `credentials` for each profile), then the following should do the trick:

```
cat ~/.aws/config | grep "\[profile " | sed -e 's/\[//g' -e 's/\]//g' -e 's/profile //g'
```

This will find all lines like this:

```
[profile foo]
[profile bar]
```

And return this:

```
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

for AWS CLI 2 there is the command

```
aws configure list-profiles
```

for AWS CLI 1 there is not a command, but if you type

```
aws configure list --profile
```

and then press tab, it will give you the names of all the profiles, then you can use the above command to inspect each profile configuration.

Comment: That has been already stated in other answer.

Comment: I didn't notice the AWS CLI 1 part in the previous answers